# Istio EnvoyFilter that checks header for a valid token

Tags: lua, istio

I need to verify that a custom header is provided with a correct value. If not, I want deny access to the service and produce a 401 with a message.

I've been able to create an Istio AuthorizationPolicy for that but it gives me 403 which isn't totally wrong but I want to be correct and give 401.

This is what I've tried so far and unfortunately it doesn't have any impact on the requests that I'm sending (I'm no envoy nor lua expert so bare with me please):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: custom-filter
  namespace: dev
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER # http connection manager is a filter in Envoy
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value: # lua filter specification
        name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              if request_handle:headers():get("auth_token") != "xxx" then
                request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "401"}, "nope")                        
              end
            end
```

Working AuthorizationPolicy that produces 403 and which I would like to replace with above:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-method-get
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  action: DENY
  rules:
  - when:
    - key: request.headers[auth_token]
      notValues: ["xxx"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, the response from istio is correct:

From RFC Standards:

> The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource...The user agent MAY repeat the request with a new or replaced Authorization header field.

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it...If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to  grant access.

So your request with token is understood but forbidden (403) but a request without token doesn't provide credentials at all, so it's unauthorized.

Regarding your filter:

Apply the Filter to `HTTP_FILTER` instead of the `NETWORK_FILTER`. And it should be applied before any other filter, so set opteration to `INSERT_BEFORE`.

**Update**

To apply the filter to a single pod instead of all pods, change context from `GATEWAY` to `SIDECAR_INBOUND`  and set a `workloadSelector` :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: custom-filter
  namespace: dev
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: my-app
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value: # lua filter specification
        name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              if request_handle:headers():get("auth_token") ~= "my_secret_token" then
                request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "401"}, "nope")                        
              end
            end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick reply. I've just tried that out but still nothing happens, the request goes through without any issues even if the token is not provided. I've also simplified the lua code to just return the request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "401"}, "nope")  without the if statement. I also tried removing the workloadSelect and applying it on the app: myapp label but still nothing happened. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, must be applied to ``istio-system`` namespace. I updated my answer. Which istio version are you using?

Comment: wow it worked! The only problem that I have now is that I would like to apply this envoy filter only on specific pods. So I added another label to the workloadSelector but as soon as I do it, it's not working (the pod is of course in another namespace).
I'm using 1.6.8. I've just noticed 1.7 was release, shall I switch to it as we have just started with istio and it's not productive yet.

Comment: I would recommand to switch to 1.7 by pruging 1.6.8 and start new with 1.7, because from what I have seen there are some bigger changes. In 6 Month 1.6 will not be supported anymore, so switch now instead of doing the work twice.

Comment: Regarding pod selection: You have set context to ``GATEWAY``, so currently the filter works on your ingress. You need to set it to ``SIDECAR_INBOUND`` and deploy the filter in the namespace of your pod. And you will need one for every pod as far as I understand. Updated my answer. If it was helpful please consider accepting!

Comment: worked like a charm with 1.7  I'll update your answer as in lua "not equals" is "~=" and not "!="